# How to align element in div in the middle

Tags: css, alignment

I've a problem with positioning my swf in the centre of the div. I have a div that I defined it's `position: top` and `left` and inside it created the second div where I load dynamically swfs with javascript. The sizes of swfs are difference so the div outside has the max-width of swfs and max-height of swfs. When I loaded swf in, it just stay in the left-top corner. I've tried with

```
.div (inside) {display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
```

and

```
.div (inside){margin-top:auto; margin-bottom: auto; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
```

and

```
.div (inside){margin-top:50%; margin-bottom: 50%; margin-left:50%; margin-right:50%;}
```

but it didn't work, when I tried to applied

```
.div (outside){padding: 25px;}
```

to the outside div the div inside moved so I think I probably should align the outside div. However when I tried
`.div (outside){padding: 50%;)` or `.div (outside)(padding: auto;)` it didn't work. 
Could anyone help me?

Comment: vertical-alight: center; change into this vertical-alight: middle; and text-align:center;

Comment: Have a look , may be it'll help you: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/flash-object-embed-tag-attributes.html , especially "align" part

Comment: try a demo http://jsfiddle.net/45MHk/107/

Comment: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center-example OR http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center

Comment: Do you actually have (inside) and (outside) in your CSS? Is there  class="div" on your divs? It would be easier to understand what's going on if you post real code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a wrapper first, and then just using the margin: 0 auto; code inside your css file?

**Basically**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="swf-container">
    <!-- Your Flash Code Here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

And then inside your CSS file, something like this..

```
div#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

div#wrapper > div.swf-container {
    display: block;
    height: 500px;
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```